# How should mount bind look like on Ubuntu? mount: bad usage

Tags: mount, bind

I am following this guide [bookstack install](https://github.com/solidnerd/docker-bookstack)

```
mount type=bind,source=/home/ubuntu/.env,target=/var/www/bookstack/.env -v /home/ubuntu:/var/www/bookstack/public/uploads -v /home/ubuntu:/var/www/bookstack/storage/uploads
```

I got

```
mount: bad usage
Try 'mount --help' for more information.
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: In the guide you're following, it says the bind mount section is a list of more options to add to the `docker run` command, not a stand-alone command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my fstab entry for a bind mount looks like this

```
 /mnt/sdb/p /home/stephen/q none bind,defaults 0 0
```

from CLI

```
# bind --mount p q
```